# Unable to stop form from submitting when validating an email

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am making a simple form that takes the value from a text input, checks if all the characters that are in an email address are there and returns true or false. According to a lot of different resources, if it returns false, then the form shouldn't be submitted. However, when I test it in JS bin, it submits it. Here's the code:

```js
function validateEmail(x) {
  console.log(x);
  var email = x.myText.value;
  console.log(email);
  var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  console.log(re.test(email));
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateEmail(this)">
  <input name="myText" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to return false if the validation fails, so simply replace

```
console.log(re.test(email));
```

with

```
return re.test(email);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/jmgo8ya2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function validateEmail(x) {
  console.log(x);
  var email = x.myText.value;
  console.log(email);
  var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change** `<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateEmail(this)">`

**With this** `<form name="myForm" onClick="return validateEmail(this)">`

*And function is like this*

`function validateEmail(x) {`

 `console.log(x);`

  `var email = x.myText.value;`

 `console.log(email);`

  `var re = your regular expression;`

  `if((re.test(email)){
document.getElementById(myForm).submit();
}`